# nested for loops in awk to count number of fields matching values

Tags: loops, awk

I have a file with two columns (1.4 million rows) that looks like:

```
CLM MXL
0 0
0 1
1 1
1 1
0 0
29 42
0 0
30 15
```

I would like to count the instances of each possible combination of values; for example if there are x number of lines where column CLM equals 0 and column MXL matches 1, I would like to print:

```
0 1 x
```

Since the maximum value of column CLM is 188 and the maximum value of column MXL is 128, I am trying to use a nested for loop in awk that looks something like:

```
awk '{for (i=0; i<=188; i++) {for (j=0; j<=128; j++) {if($9==i && $10==j) {print$0}}}}' 1000Genomes.ALL.new.txt > test
```

But this only prints out the original file, which makes sense, I just don't know how to correctly write a for loop that prints out one file for each combination of values, which I can then wc, or print out one file with counts of each combination. Any solution in awk, bash script, perl script would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1. A Pure `awk` Solution

```
$ awk 'NR>1{c[$0]++} END{for (k in c)print k,c[k]}' file | sort -n
0 0 3
0 1 1
1 1 2
29 42 1
30 15 1
```

#### How it works

The code uses a single variable `c`.  `c` is an associative array whose keys are lines in the file and whose values are the number of occurrences.

- `NR>1{c[$0]++}`

  For every line except the first (which has the headings), this increments the count for the combination in that line.
- `END{for (k in c)print k,c[k]}`

  This prints out the final counts.
- `sort -n`

  This is just for aesthetics: it puts the output lines in a predictable order.

### 2. Alternative using `uniq -c`

```
$ tail -n+2 file | sort -n | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$3,$1}'
0 0 3
0 1 1
1 1 2
29 42 1
30 15 1
```

#### How it works

- `tail -n+2 file`

  This prints all but the first line of the file.  The purpose of this is to remove the column headings.
- `sort -n | uniq -c`

  This sorts the lines and then counts the duplicates.
- `awk '{print $2,$3,$1}`

  `uniq -c` puts the counts first and you wanted the counts to be the last on the line.  This just rearranges the columns to the format that you wanted.